# JavaFX - Mover ventana sin bordes arrastrando un anchorpane

Tags: javafx

Estoy haciendo un programa donde ocupo mover un Stage undecorated, el cual contiene un anchorPane como título. Ese anchorPane lo quiero arrastrar y mover la ventana, pero no logro escribir el evento mouse pressed y mouse drag.

Si alguien conoce una mejor forma de mover una venta sin bordes, lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo he realizado esta interfaz:

```
public interface DraggedScene {

    default void onDraggedScene(AnchorPane panelFather) {
        AtomicReference<Double> xOffset = new AtomicReference<>((double) 0);
        AtomicReference<Double> yOffset = new AtomicReference<>((double) 0);

        panelFather.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            Stage stage = (Stage) panelFather.getScene().getWindow();
            xOffset.set(stage.getX() - e.getScreenX());
            yOffset.set(stage.getY() - e.getScreenY());

        });

        panelFather.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            Stage stage = (Stage) panelFather.getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setX(e.getScreenX() + xOffset.get());
            stage.setY(e.getScreenY() + yOffset.get());
            panelFather.setStyle("-fx-cursor: CLOSED_HAND;");
        });

        panelFather.setOnMouseReleased(e-> panelFather.setStyle("-fx-cursor: DEFAULT;"));


    }
}
```

Nota: El metodo onDraggedScene es llamado en el metodo initialize en cada controlador del FXML luego de este implementar la interfaz Initializable, a dicho metodo se le pasa el panel padre en el fxml.

Ejemplo de su uso:

```
public class ContainerController implements Initializable,DraggedScene {
 @FXML
 AnchorPane container;

 @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        this.onDraggedScene(this.container);
    }

}
```